# Show all symbols in legend in spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat

I'm plotting a forest with trees as in the sample data `lansing` in `spatstat`.
My code is as in this example:

```
plot(lansing, cols=rainbow(length(unique(lansing$marks))),
         leg.args=list(y.intersp = .5, cex = .2, pt.cex = .2))
```

But I have 14 tree species, so I receive the warning that only 10 are shown in the symbol map. Is there a way to show them all? I tried different ways, e.g. `y.intersp`, which brought no error, but also no response.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legend in `plot.ppp()` is also called a `symbolmap` and the plotting
of the legend is done by `plot.symbolmap()` which defaults to only plotting
10 types of points. You can override it by setting `nsymbols = 14`. To set
this argument from `plot.ppp()` you can use the argument `leg.args`:

```r
library(spatstat)
X <- rmpoint(100, win = owin(), types = letters[1:14])
s <- plot(X, leg.args = list(nsymbols = 14))
```

[image]

The return value of `plot.ppp()` is the `symbolmap` used so you can reuse the
same `symbolmap` in another plot. You can also plot the `symbolmap` itself:

```r
plot(s, main = "", vertical = TRUE)
#> Warning: Only 10 out of 14 symbols are shown in the symbol map
```

[image]

```r
plot(s, nsymbols = 14, main = "", vertical = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: This works just perfectly. Thank you very much for your code and the explanation :-)